# scanf() to iterate through an unknown quantity of integers

Tags: c, integer, scanf

So I'm trying to find the sum of an unknown amount of user-input numbers. Here's my code

```
int main()
{
    int tmp1 = 1;
    int tmp2 = 1;
    int total = 0;

    printf("Enter numbers for a sum: ");
    tmp2 = scanf(" %d", &tmp1);

    while(tmp2 > 0){
        total+=tmp1;
        tmp2 = scanf(" %d", &tmp1);
    }
    printf("total is %d", total);

    return 0;
}
```

It gets stuck in an endless loop, and then once i hit ctrl-c to end it, it prints the correct sum. So what I'm doing wrong is how will i know when it's done scanning all the integers, and for the loop to end; since i'm not doing it correctly now

Comment: Do you know for sure that there are only integers in the input?  If there were decimal points, alphabet, or other special characters, it would not work.  Otherwise, what I see ought to work, at least for some implementations of `scanf()`.

Comment: Instead of "doesn't work", say what you expected to happen, and what actually happened. And post real code instead of "something like" the real code. [The code you actually posted is OK](http://ideone.com/BKNlgM)

Comment: It also depends on how the numbers are delimited. Are they on the same line with whitespace between them? Is each number on its own individual line? A mix of the two? It makes a difference in how you read the input and scan for the numbers.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It doesn't do anything. I put "something like this" because i'm really in the trial and error phase trying stuff and that was what i was experimenting with. I'm sorry if it didn't seem content enough. I assumed there would be a very simple answer. I updated it to show more code of what i'm working with now

Comment: @Dad it doesn't seem to be updated. See my sample program from my previous comment.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I tested the code you supplied above, and I'm running into the same issue I'm getting in my revised post now

Comment: @Dad you have to decide how you are going to indicate that you have finished. The program can't read your mind. As things stand you can press ^D (or ^Z on windows), or you can type in something that's not a number, e.g. `quit`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't understand, it's a line of numbers. It should stop after it's done reading all the numbers. How would I be able to know once all the numbers are read, and for the loop to terminate? This is supposed to be automatic, so pressing ^D isn't really a viable solution

Comment: Post real code `total+=tmp;`, there is no `tmp`.

Comment: @chux "Enter numbers for a sum: 4 5 7 2"

Comment: Note: using meaningful variable names rather than `tmp1`, `tmp2` self-documents the code.  Without it, the code's intention is much harder to decipher.

Comment: @Dad how does it know if you've finished typing yet? Maybe you were going to type more numbers but you just stopped to have a sip of your coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to make it stop via ctrl d, and its acceptable. thanks

Comment: Dad, avoid answering your own question (it makes the flow of a question difficult to follow). If you need to add to, or alter, your original question in some way, `edit` your question. However, please just `add to` your question and avoid changing the original substance of your original code. That can render answers prior to your edit inapplicable. All of this just makes the site more readable/useful to others that can learn from your question.

Comment: @David C. Rankin In general, I agree that questions should have added edits if the nature of the question _must_ change.  But OP here should accept an answer that solves the question.  It it turns out to be a self answer - so be it.  I lost time trying to hit the moving target.

Comment: Agreed. If the OP has answered his question, then an answer-to-own is fine. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, it is not clear how you expect your programme to understand that there won't be anymore numbers to input. Shall it be through a specific character? Or shall it just get a line of space-separated numbers and respond with a sum?

From your code, my most sensible guess is: You want it to understand that there won't be any more numbers to add, whenever it encounters a non-digital character. My guess is so, because this is almost exactly what your code does by checking the return value from `scanf`.

First of all, you have to change that `tmp` inside your loop into `tmp1` because there isn't such a variable as `tmp` declared. *edit: well, never mind*

Then try running your programme, putting in any amount of white-space (space, tab or new-line) separated numbers, and then any non-digital character you like. May be a `T` for example, or `ThoAppelsin`, it won't matter. Programme won't get beyond the first character, in fact, not even beyond the first character. After that, you shall see that the numbers have been properly added together.

Since you're confused about a non-existent infinite-loop, my second guess is that you might be actually hoping it to get a single line of space-delimited numbers, and have the sum printed; and misinterpret your programme as "in infinite loop" while it merely expects further input from you, just like it does at the very beginning.

You won't get a `0` from non-redirected `scanf("%d", &var);`, unless you feed it with something that doesn't match to the format string to cause abnormal termination. If there's nothing left in the input stream to consume, it will just wait for more input. But say you give an `'a'` to it, then all it can do is to give up and return zero, because it couldn't do a single assignment.

If you really are hoping to have a single line of numbers, then the minimal change I could offer would be something like this:

int main(void)
    {
        int tmp1 = 1;
        char tmp2 = 0;
        int total = 0;

```
    printf("Enter numbers for a sum: ");
    scanf("%d%c", &tmp1, &tmp2);

    while(tmp2 == ' '){
        total+=tmp1;
        scanf("%d%c", &tmp1, &tmp2);
    }
    printf("total is %d", total);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this approach has many vulnerabilities. However, if user is to input strictly a sequence like:

```
3 66 2 10 6

// mind the new-line
```

It will work fine. But if I'm allowed to change more than minimal, this is how I would do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int LastNumber = 0;
    int UpcomingCharacter = 0;
    int Total = 0;

    printf("Enter numbers for a sum: ");
    while(scanf("%d%*[ \t]", &LastNumber) == 1)
    {
        Total += LastNumber;
        UpcomingCharacter = getchar( );
        if (!isdigit(UpcomingCharacter)) // eliminates a possible EOF return as well
            break;
        if (ungetch(UpcomingCharacter, stdin) != UpcomingCharacter)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: unexpected error with ungetch\n", __LINE__);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    printf("total is %d", Total);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which should work fine on any whitespace-delimited sequence of numbers, excluding the new-lines of course.

Comment: OP was at least checking the result of the `scanf()`.  Also doing so here would improve this answer.

Comment: @chux I was trying to make the least amount of changes there. I've added another suggestion that wasn't restricted by any means, and that's all I can offer for this question really.

Comment: Minor: 1) default C local: "any whitespace" includes `' '`, `'\f'`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'` and `'\v'`. C11dr §7.4.1.10 2  2) `if (!isdigit(UpcomingCharacter))` does not take into account `'-'` nor `'+'`.